# Why can't I clone a `Vec` of cloneable constructors?

Tags: rust, clone, lifetime, trait-objects

I have a structure wrapping a Vec of `Box<dyn Any>` constructors which I've asserted to be clone.

I have a trait `Ctor` which takes the clone logic and produces another `Box<dyn Ctor>`. It compiles fine if I don't implement the trait or if I don't call the clone function.

But if I do both, I get a weird message claiming data escapes its lifetime bounds even though I've asserted the value is `'static`.

(The code is much easier to read than the above description but stackoverflow complains if you don't have enough english text in your post and nitpickers complain if you put lorem ipsum in your stackoverflow posts)

Uncommenting either block below compiles fine, but uncommenting both blocks simultaneously results in an error:

```
use std::any::Any;

// pub struct SVConstructor {
//     ctors: Vec<Box<dyn Ctor + 'static>>,
// }

// impl Clone for SVConstructor {
//     fn clone(&self) -> Self {
//         let Self { ctors } = self;
//         let mut new_ctors: Vec<Box<dyn Ctor + 'static>> = Vec::new();
//         for ctor in ctors {
//             let value: Box<dyn Ctor + 'static> = ctor.clone_box();
//             drop(ctor);
//             new_ctors.push(value);
//         }
//         Self { ctors: new_ctors }
//     }
// }

pub trait Ctor: Fn() -> Box<dyn Any + Send + Sync + 'static> + Send + Sync {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Ctor + 'static>;
}

// impl<T: Fn() -> Box<dyn Any + Send + Sync + 'static> + Send + Sync + Clone + 'static> Ctor for T {
//     fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Ctor + 'static> {
//         Box::new(self.clone())
//     }
// }
```

When I uncomment everything I get:

> ```
> error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
>   --> src/lib.rs:12:50
>    |
> 8  |     fn clone(&self) -> Self {
>    |              -----
>    |              |
>    |              `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
>    |              let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
> ...
> 12 |             let value: Box<dyn Ctor + 'static> = ctor.clone_box();
>    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    |                                                  |
>    |                                                  `self` escapes the associated function body here
>    |                                                  argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.
> ```

Comment: nit: `Any + 'static` is redundant since `trait Any: 'static`

Comment: I just started tacking `'static` onto everything everywhere trying to get the compiler to stop complaining

Comment: i'd argue it's a bad habit to try and silence the compiler. if we start doing that, rust becomes no better or safer than c.

Comment: @RobertCotterman While it's clearly a bad idea to "silence the compiler" without understanding what one is doing, the reason you give is untrue. Safe Rust will not allow unsound code to compile, even regardless of whether the author understands annotations like `'static` or not. More importantly, almost everyone who wrote more than "hello world" in Rust has been guilty of doing so at one point or another. A novice shouldn't feel guilty for occasionally doing the same.

Comment: @RobertCotterman I don't do that in real code. The point here was to narrow down the possibilities for where the complaint was coming from. There's a difference between what MWE-for-StackOverflow code and actual production code look like. When you want to isolate something weird, sticking annotations on everything everywhere is great (as long as you delete it when done)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ctors` is of type `&Vec<Box<dyn Ctor + 'static>>` in the for loop and `&Box<dyn Ctor + 'static>` also implements `Fn() -> Box<dyn Any + Send + Sync> + Send + Sync` (the same `Fn` trait is implemented for both [`Box<F>` and `&F`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#implementors)) and `Clone` (all references are `Copy`) so you're calling `clone_box` with `T` of `&Box<dyn Ctor + 'static>` and that leads to you cloning the reference along with it's lifetime instead of cloning the `Ctor` inside the `Box`. The solution is to get rid of that extra reference:

```rust
impl Clone for SVConstructor {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        let Self { ctors } = self;
        let mut new_ctors: Vec<Box<dyn Ctor + 'static>> = Vec::new();
        for ctor in ctors {
            let value: Box<dyn Ctor + 'static> = (*ctor).clone_box();
            new_ctors.push(value);
        }
        Self { ctors: new_ctors }
    }
}
```

Because `ctor` is only a reference the `drop(ctor)` doesn't do anything either so you can remove it as well.
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e45418a597fed0062d7ab2aac314ec77)

Comment: Everytime i feel i'm starting to grasp rust, i read an answer like this.